# how to invoke convertback of a control that has a converter assigned to it in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

how do i invoke convertback method on a control say textbox or button that has been assigned converter in the xaml markup. I need to get the binding value instead of the displayed value. the content property gives the displayed value but i need the original binding value.

Answer (score 0):

You should set [BindingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx) to `TwoWay`. This will invoke your ConvertBack method. If you need actual original binding value then my guess would be to create custom attached behavior and remember value with the help of it.